# Scanner input gets appended to textfile despite condition in while-loop

Tags: java, terminal, filewriter

I have a small little Java application that, on Terminal execution, will take string inputs, and saves those strings to a text file. I have the string `exit` that would prompt the application to exit. However, for some reason, the string `exit` gets appended to the document despite having that `while(!)` loop. What could be the issue?

```
try{
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = null;
            while(!"exit".equalsIgnoreCase(input)){
                input = scanner.nextLine();
                String fileLocation = "/Users/myName/Dropbox/myDocument.txt";
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileLocation,true);

                writer.append(returnDate()+": ");
                writer.append(input + "\n");

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Your code has too many issues. You are checking the loop condition after it's processed. You are also creating a new FileWriter over and over again the loop. Move FileWriter outside of the loop. Use `scanner.hasNextLine()` as your loop condition and then check if the input matches "exit" string.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the filewriter issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow your code mentally. You do all the processing in the loop, *before* the while loop condition is evaluated the next time through.

You have:

```
while(!"exit".equalsIgnoreCase(input)){
    input = scanner.nextLine(); 
    ...
    writer.append(input + "\n");
    ...
}
```

Assuming the user types "exit" as the first command, the flow is:

1. `input` is `null` initially.
2. `while` condition succeeds.
3. `input` is read, it is now "exit".
4. `input`, i.e. "exit", is written to file.
5. `while` loop restarts, condition is evaluated, fails, loop does not execute again.

Note that "exit" was written to the file.

You will have to rework your logic a bit to make sure that the file write does not occur. This is not an uncommon type of situation. There are many solutions depending on your preference. You could combine the assignment and comparison into the `while` statement:

```
while (!"exit".equalsIgnoreCase(input = scanner.nextLine())) {
    write input;
}
```

You could have a redundant check (doesn't make sense for your simple example and also frequently indicates room for overall logic improvement):

```
while (input is not exit) { 
    read input;
    if (input is not exit) write input;
}
```

You could not use the loop condition at all:

```
while (true) {
    read input; 
    if (input is exit) break;
    write input;
}
```

There are many ways to fix it.

Comment: Ah. I can see that now.